# unknown switch `1` error while using rvm

Tags: ruby, rvm, rvmrc

I recently migrated from **oh-my-zsh** -> **bash** -> **prezto**. During all this I somehow messed up my rvm. Now whenever I run `rvm use` or `rvm use 1.9.2` or even while loading .rvmrc, I get the following error:

```
error: unknown switch `1'
usage: git rebase [-i] [options] [--onto <newbase>] [<upstream>] [<branch>]
   or: git rebase [-i] [options] --onto <newbase> --root [<branch>]
   or: git-rebase [-i] --continue | --abort | --skip

Available options are
    -v, --verbose         display a diffstat of what changed upstream
    -q, --quiet           be quiet. implies --no-stat
    --onto ...            rebase onto given branch instead of upstream
    -p, --preserve-merges
                          try to recreate merges instead of ignoring them
    -s, --strategy ...    use the given merge strategy
    --no-ff               cherry-pick all commits, even if unchanged
    -m, --merge           use merging strategies to rebase
    -i, --interactive     let the user edit the list of commits to rebase
    -f, --force-rebase    force rebase even if branch is up to date
    -X, --strategy-option ...
                          pass the argument through to the merge strategy
    --stat                display a diffstat of what changed upstream
    -n, --no-stat         do not show diffstat of what changed upstream
    --verify              allow pre-rebase hook to run
    --rerere-autoupdate   allow rerere to update index with resolved conflicts
    --root                rebase all reachable commits up to the root(s)
    --autosquash          move commits that begin with squash!/fixup! under -i
    --committer-date-is-author-date
                          passed to 'git am'
    --ignore-date         passed to 'git am'
    --whitespace ...      passed to 'git apply'
    --ignore-whitespace   passed to 'git apply'
    -C ...                passed to 'git apply'

Actions:
    --continue            continue
    --abort               abort and check out the original branch
    --skip                skip current patch and continue

Using /Users/ankitgoyal/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320
```

I tried uninstalling `rvm` completely and reinstalling it, but it didn't work. I just can't figure out where is it running `git rebase`.

This error is really annoying. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check your aliases and environment:

```
alias | grep rebase
env   | grep rebase
```

possibly:

```
alias | grep git
env   | grep git
```

in worst case there could be a function

```
typeset -f | grep rebase
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. There seems to be a problem with git module of prezto. I disabled its git module and it worked.